# "LB" component reference designator

Tags: components, identification, reference

I'm doing a bit of reverse engineering on my [Das Keyboard Model S Ultimate](http://www.daskeyboard.com/model-s-ultimate/%23/awesome-products). I'm beginning to develop a pretty good understanding of the circuitry, but I am confused about one type of component on the board.

There are 4-5 components on this board with the reference designator of LB. This isn't a standard refdes that I'm aware of and I can't think of anything that I would label as LB. What might this component be? You can see one of them pictured here near the smaller connector.

[image: Picture of board with unidentified component]

**Description**: They look to be about the same size as an 0805 capacitor but gray instead of that brownish color of a cap. It isn't as dark as a resistor either.

Comment: Any chance that is "FB"? Ferrite Bead?

Comment: Measure the DC resistance.

Comment: It appears to be LB not FB, and unfortunately my multimeter is currently out of commission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely a ferrite bead. The lb would stand for inductor bead. Looking at the board it may be a filter on the small connector's power or ground pin.

Comment: Yes that appears to be the case. They are placed near all of the connectors that carry power as well as on the output of the only on-board LDO. Can't imagine why they'd use LB rather than FB but oh well. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelLeonard Well, L would be the normal ref des for an inductor, so it makes sense.